# Configuration IIS 7 for JSON

Tags: json, iis

i have this code for receiving data from server:

```
try
{
  var data = _model.GetAll().ToList();
  if (data.Count > 100)
    return SendMessage($"Too much results", HttpStatusCode.Forbidden);
  var result = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data,
                new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new JsonConverter[] { new StringEnumConverter() } });
  return SendMessage(new{ results = result });
}catch (Exception ex)
{
  return SendMessage("Server error.", HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
}
```

SendMessage method:

```
protected JsonResult SendMessage(string message, object data, HttpStatusCode code = HttpStatusCode.OK)
{
   Response.StatusCode = (int)code;
   return Json(new { message, data }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

When method return 403 http code, i localhost is everything ok. Method send data in content-type application/json. But when I deploy my code to web server (IIS 7) method send content-type text/html and data is empty.
Where is problem? How i must configure IIS server?

Thanks for advices

Comment: I find where is problem. In product IIS server response default IIS error page, dont response my JSON. How I can configure IIS to response custom http code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is solution for my problem: https://forums.iis.net/t/1213176.aspx.

Open your IIS > click web site > Error Pages > here under "Alerts" section click on "Edit Features Settings..." it will show following three option :

1] Custom error pages

2] Detail errors

3] Detailed errors for local requests and custom error pages for remote requestes.

select 2nd option Detail errors click Ok.